# PHP: secure way to send password via post

Tags: php, html, authentication, https

I am very interested in php and login forms. However, I am still struggling what is safe to do and what not.

When a user logs in, I need to send the username and password via POST to a php.

- At the moment I am hashing the password on the server with php function. The hashed password is stored in the database aswell.
- I read you can hash it already with JS on client side? But what happens when js is not activated? I can't be sure that it is 100% correctly hashed.
- Is it safe to send a plain password via post but with HTTPS?

Thanks for your input. I am happy to learn some new techniques to make it even safer.

Comment: As long as you send it via HTTPS, you're good. Even big sites do it without using any additional encryption of the password string.

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. You should never store passwords in any form on the server. Only store secure hashes.

Comment: Thank you @ConstantinGroß That is good to know.

Comment: Regarding storage of passwords, you should not rely on a standard hashing function like `sha1` (and especially not `md5`). Read up on "salting" passwords and/or use dedicated password hashing algorithms/libraries.

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. [Hash them!](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself wrong, I am using password_hash function in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you send a plain password via HTTPS to your server, and your server will hash it there and store the hashed password in a database.

You also might read about CSRF protection. In every post request you should integrate an CSRF protection.

In theorie a hacker could recreate your frontend website with a form. The user that visit his page will think its your page and he will try to register/login into your page. With no CSRF protection the user will be able to login and will be redirected to your site for example a Dashboard and the hacker could then save these information in his database.